# When $x= \pm \sqrt{y-1}$, is $y$ a function of $x$? How to deal with the $\pm$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am solving equations to find if y is a function of x.  The equation I am solving for y is; $$x= \pm \sqrt{y-1}$$

I am wondering what to do with the $\pm$ sign?  I did take the one equation and made two out of it.  I think if I can do that then the rest of the answer is all algebraic.  Here are my two equations.

$x=\sqrt{y-1}$, and $x=- \sqrt{y-1}$

Then I square both sides of each equation;

$x^2=y-1$, and $x^2=-(y-1)$

Then distribute the negative in the second equation

$x^2=y-1$, and $x^2= -y+1$

Then I isolate the y on one side of the equation

$-y=-x^2-1$, and $y=-x^2+1$

Then the first equation there is -y.  I multiply that equation by -1 to finish getting y by itself.

$y=x^2+1$, and $y=-x^2+1$
Is this the right method to solve for $\pm$?  Can it be solved any further?  I thought it would be complete.

All the books says is that y is a function of x for this equation.  It doesn’t show how to solve.

Answer (score 3):

We start with

$x = \pm \sqrt{y-1} \implies x^2 = (\pm \sqrt{y-1})^2 = \lvert \sqrt{y-1} \rvert^2 = y-1$.

Now we have

$x^2 = y-1 \implies y = x^2 + 1$

In order for $y$ to be a function of $x$ it is necessary that for each input of $x$ we get exactly one output $y$. In other words, if we take $x_1$ we mustn't have $x_1^2+1 = y_1$ and $x_1^2+1 = y_2$ where $y_1 \neq y_2$.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Can you tell me more about why absolute value can replace the $\pm$?  I think it is because the number regardless of being positive or negative still has the same magnitude?   

A relationship is a set of ordered pairs.  A function is a relationship where the x never repeats itself.  I think this helps with if an equation is a function or not.  I am still a bit turned around on the solving.

Comment: @Benp404 If we have $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $(-x)^2 = x^2$ and moreover, $\lvert - x\rvert^2  = \lvert x\rvert^2 = \lvert x^2 \rvert = \lvert (-x)^2 \rvert$. This seems potentially redundant but what I hope it illustrates is absolute value and squaring allow us to drop the $\pm$. I could have omitted the absolute value, since squaring a negative number results in the same outcome as squaring a positive. Sometimes it is beneficial to add more information than necessary in a computation/proof to convince ourselves and develop understanding.

Comment: If x is an element of all real numbers we are saying that x in our problem cannot be in the set of imaginary numbers?  This is true because we are squaring a number.  our answer will always be positive no matter if the number we are evaluating is negative or positive.  We will never end up with an imaginary number for that reason.  Imaginary numbers are always caused by a negative?  But, I don't think $(-x)^2$ and $ - (x)^2$ are the same thing.  To me the negative is multiplied to the number after the exponential operation is complete and the solution has to have two equations.

Comment: I missed the final parentheses in my final answer on the initial post.  It should read $y=x^2 +1$ and $y=-(x)^2+1$.  The reason why I think this answer is right is because the $\pm$ is on the outside of the radical.  $x=\pm \sqrt{y-1}$.  I would think that after squaring both sides of the question I would end up with $x^2=\pm(y-1)$

Comment: Indeed, $(-x)^2 \neq -(x)^2 $ and if say $x=i$ then $x^2 = -1$ but if $z = \pm x \in \mathbb{C}$ then $z = \pm (a+bi)$ so we have $z^2 = (\pm a +bi )^2$ and $(-a-bi)^2 = (a+bi)^2$. For instance $z = \pm (-2+3i)$ then $(-2+3i)^2 = -5-12i =  (2-3i)^2$. And no, the $\pm$ goes inside the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake is $x^2=-(y-1)$. Then the next step was to distribute the - in from of the parentheses.  The equation then is $x^2=-y+1$.  I had forgotten I did that step.  Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: @Benp404 No you are doing it wrong, you have in your post, $x = \pm \sqrt{y-1}$, then $x^2 = y-1$, there is no minus sign left outside after squaring.

Comment: Is this what your saying is the way to do it?  I’ll start with the initial equation and go through the process of removing the radical.  $x=\pm \ sqrt{1-y}$.  Then I square both sides to get rid of the radical and that looks like this $$x^2=(\pm \sqrt{1-y})^2$$

Comment: Is this what your saying is the way to do it?  I’ll start with the initial equation and go through the process of removing the radical.  $x=\pm \ sqrt{1-y}$.  Then I square both sides to get rid of the radical and that looks like this $$x^2=(\pm \sqrt{1-y})^2$$. 

I was think there about the $\pm$ as being $( \pm1)^2$. If I square a negative 1 or a positive 1 the answer is the same.  Is that wrong?  I think that is what I wasn’t doing when I broke the equation in to two parts.  I can that according to the initial equation $x=/sqrt{1-y}$ and $x=-\sqrt{1-y}$. But not necessary.

Comment: @Benp404 Re-read my submitted answer, I am not sure what is not clear.

Comment: I see it now thanks

Answer (score 2):

Be careful. $x=\pm y\implies x^2=y^2$ *not* $x^2=\pm y^2$. Indeed, $$y=1-x^2\implies x^2=1-y\implies x=\pm\sqrt{1-y}\neq\pm\sqrt{y-1}$$

However, $y=x^2+1$ is valid: $$y=x^2+1\implies x^2=y-1\implies x=\pm\sqrt{y-1}$$

Comment: Why can’t $x^2=\pm y^2$?  Is  it because the domain and range no longer meet the definition of a function?

Comment: $$x=\pm y\implies x^2=(\pm y) ^2=(\pm 1)^2y^2=y^2$$ because $(\pm 1)^2=1$. On the contrary, $$x=\pm iy\implies x^2=(\pm i) ^2y^2=-y^2$$ because $(\pm i) ^2=-1$